# Find via SSH em vários servidores

Tags: shell-script, ssh

Uma das minhas atividades na empresa que trabalho é verificar log de JVMs quando temos erros na aplicação.

A forma que é feita essa verificação é através de SSH (temos um "túnel" configurado através de VPN diretamente configurada no SONICWALL).

Funciona assim:

```
$ ssh [servidor interno] (utilizo ALIAS, o host está configurado na minha chave)
$ssh [servidor cliente] (não temos mais acesso direto)
```

Dentro do servidor do cliente temos 2 JVMs (criamos links das pastas de logs para não ter que ficar navegando até elas), mas para acessar as pastas precisamos voltar um diretório (não sei porque o usuário da empresa não loga no diretório raiz), ficando:

```
$ cd
```

Resumindo a rotina:

```
$ ssh [servidor empresa]
$ ssh [servidor cliente]
$ cd
$ cd [log_vm_1]
$ find ./* -type f -exec grep -l COD_ERRO_JVM  {} \;
```

Não é um processo muito longo, o problema é que temos 5 servidores com 2 VMs cada, e a aplicação é gerenciada por um WebLogic (não temos como saber onde ocorreu o erro), ou seja, tenho que procurar VM por VM.

A minha dúvida é:

É possível criar um script onde eu rode este `find` em todos os servidores/VMs ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente você pode criar um script que faz a busca nas duas JVMs de um mesmo servidor:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd
for dir in log_vm_1 log_vm_2
do
    echo "procurando em" $(hostname) $dir
    find $dir -type f -exec grep -l COD_ERRO_JVM  {} \;
done
```

Repare que você não precisa fazer `cd dir` e depois `find`, é possível passar o diretório diretamente para o `find`. Aliás, se você sabe o caminho completo do diretório, nem mesmo o `cd` no começo é necessário, você poderia fazer simplesmente `find /caminho/completo/log_vm`.

Na verdade, se quiser, pode passar vários diretórios de uma vez: `find log_vm_1 log_vm_2`, assim nem precisaria do `for`. Eu fiz o `for` acima apenas para ter um `echo` entre um diretório e outro, assim as respectivas saídas ficam visualmente mais separadas.

---

Supondo que o script acima esteja salvo no arquivo `busca.sh` (em alguma pasta do seu servidor interno), basta você se conectar em cada um dos servidores do cliente passando o nome do script como parâmetro:

```
ssh servidor_interno
for serv in  servidor_cliente_1  servidor_cliente_2  servidor_cliente_3
do
    ssh $serv "bash -s" < /pasta/do/arquivo/busca.sh
done
```

[`"bash -s" < arquivo`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=bash%20-s) faz com que os comandos sejam lidos do arquivo. Em seguida, eles são executados no servidor do cliente, sem que o script precise estar lá.

Com isso os comandos do script `busca.sh` são executados em cada um dos servidores do cliente. A linha com `echo` imprime o `hostname` e o diretório, assim você terá uma saída parecida com isso:

```
procurando em servidor_cliente_1 log_vm_1
... saída do find 
procurando em servidor_cliente_1 log_vm_2
... saída do find
procurando em servidor_cliente_2 log_vm_1
... saída do find 
procurando em servidor_cliente_2 log_vm_2
... saída do find
... e assim por diante
```

Claro que você pode salvar o `for serv ...` acima em outro script, se quiser. Por exemplo, se eu salvar em `/pasta/busca_todos.sh` (no servidor interno) e der permissão de execução (`chmod u+x busca_todos.sh`), eu posso executá-lo diretamente pelo SSH:

```
ssh servidor_interno /pasta/busca_todos.sh
```

Assim, ao se logar no servidor interno, o script `busca_todos.sh` é executado. E dentro dele existe o `for` que faz um *loop* por todos os servidores do cliente, executando a busca em cada um deles.

---

Outra alternativa é copiar o script `busca.sh` para cada um dos servidores do cliente:

```
scp busca.sh servidor_cliente_1:/pasta
scp busca.sh servidor_cliente_2:/pasta
... copiar para todos os servidores do cliente
```

Como agora existe uma cópia do arquivo em cada servidor do cliente, basta passar o caminho completo do mesmo ao fazer o SSH:

```
ssh servidor_interno
for serv in  servidor_cliente_1  servidor_cliente_2  servidor_cliente_3
do
    ssh $serv /pasta/busca.sh
done
```

Lembrando que o script deve ter permissão de execução (é necessário executar `chmod u+x busca.sh` em cada servidor do cliente para que ele possa ser executado).

Comment: hkotsubo,

Muito obrigado. Deu certo.

Comment: @RodrigoSantos Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.